# How to prove that pairs of probability are independent?

Tags: probability, independence

Given the following probabilities:

***p(A|C) = 0.5,

p(A|C') = 0,

p(B|C') = 0.6,

p(B'|C) = 0.4,

p(C) = 0.3***

How do I prove which of the pairs containing A,B and A,C are independent, without having any information about P(A) or P(B)?

Comment: HINT: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $P(X|Y)=P(X|Y')$

Comment: yes, my first thought was , if p(A|C') = 0, it must be independent since one of the events has to be zero, is that correct?

Comment: No. $p(A\mid C')=0$ indicates that $A$ will not occur when $C$ does not occur.  However, since $p(A\mid C)$ is not zero, clearly the occurrence of A does depend on whether or not C does occur.

Comment: @huzuz No, you can't conclude that just from $p(A|C')=0$ ... In fact, we know that $p(A|C)\neq 0$, telling  us that $A$ and $C$ are *not* independent!

Comment: oh i see! my bad, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For independent events $A$ and $B$ we must have$$P(A|B)=P(A)$$We proceed by$$P(A)=P(A|C)P(C)+P(A|C')P(C')=0.15$$$$P(B){=P(B|C)P(C)+P(B|C')P(C')\\=[1-P(B'|C)]P(C)+P(B|C')P(C')\\=0.6P(C)+0.6P(C')\\=0.6}$$Since $$P(A)\ne P(A|C)\\P(B)=P(B|C)$$then **$A$ and $C$ are mutually dependent and $B$ and $C$ are mutually independent**.